# Bootstrap table pages by column values

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using a bootstrap table where I can choose the page size by the

```
pageSize: 10,
pageList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200],
```

parameters.

What I would like to do is to get the pages not of a fixed size, but dividing all the row by the values of one column. So for example if I have a column for salaries and 13 people have a salary 3500€ and 8 people have a salary 4000€, then I'd like to have the 13 entries on 1 table-page and the other 8 entries on the other table-page. I would like to make this work particularly for dates or date ranges.

What I've understood from the documentation, is that this feature does not exist, but I hope to get some alternative solutions for my Django-run page.

Answer (score 0):

I am handling a similar situation, but not with paging. I have select2 dropbox boxes where the user select the parameter(s) and then I populate the grid with those choice(s). https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Here is a sample of the code I am using the pass parameters to the server application.

```
$('#comptable1').bootstrapTable({
    url: 'urlhere.php',
    pagination: true,
    sidePagination: 'server',
    uniqueId: 'id',
    selectItemName: 'chkID',
    columns:[
        {
            ...
        }
    ],
    queryParams: function(params){
        //add paramaters to the params array as needed
        params['field']=$('#findfield').val();

        return params;
    }
});
```